# Can deities from other universes hear our prayers?

Tags: gods, philosophy

Can deities inhabiting other universes hear our prayers, or is it just the presiding deities of this universe?

Comment: you are making, a priori, the scientific speculation that there are other universes.

Comment: I don't think I am, other universes have been talked about in many Hindu scriptures.

"Of those countless universes, O Rama, in some there are only plants; some have Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra and others as the presiding deities, and some have none at all; in some there are only animals and birds; in some there is only an ocean; some are solid rocks; some are inhabited only by worms; some are pervaded by dense darkness some are forever illumined. Some seem to be heading towards dissolution; some seem to be falling in space towards destruction." (Section III. Utpatti Prakaranam - chapter 29-30)